Angular file upload is slower than postman

I have one nodejs API which is taking formdata file as an input and uploads video file into my disk

from postman i am making POST request with 700MB file which is uploading as expected speed

but from angular if i make http post request to send file to my backend, it is uploading at very slow speed and it is getting aborted in between.

I have tried to directly uplod file from postman, it works fine



you should include your angular code.  (the bit that sends/creates formdata object...)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
